# How to walk directory till first-level using nodejs walk module

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory

I have below directory structure

```
 Ranveers-MacBook-Air:custom-feeds ranveer$ ls    /Users/ranveer/custom-feeds
README.md   cartridges  sites
Ranveers-MacBook-Air:custom-feeds ranveer$
```

I want to traverse the above directory and in output I only need first-directory(i.e first-level)

Desired output (directory + full path)

1. /Users/ranveer/custom-feeds/cartridges
2. /Users/ranveer/custom-feeds/sites

I tried using below code to generate my desired output

```
walk = require('walk');
walker = walk.walk('/Users/ranveer/custom-feeds');
walker.on('directories' , (root, dirStatsArray, next) => {
    console.log(dirStatsArray);
    next();
});
```

I get below output in node console

```
> walker.on('directories' , (root, dirStatsArray, next) => {
...     console.log(dirStatsArray);
...     next();
... });
Walker {
  domain:
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] },
  _events: { directories: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _wStat: 'lstat',
  _wStatSync: 'lstatSync',
  _wsync: false,
  _wq: [],
  _wqueue: [],
  _wcurpath: '/Users/ranveer/custom-feeds/.git/logs/refs/heads',
  _wfilters: [],
  _wfirstrun: true,
  _wWalk: [Function],
  _wfnodegroups:
   { files: [ [Object] ],
     directories: [],
     symbolicLinks: [],
     blockDevices: [],
     characterDevices: [],
     FIFOs: [],
     sockets: [],
     nodes: [],
     errors: [] },
  _wcurfiles: [ 'master' ],
  _wcurfile: 'master',
  _wCurFileCallback: [Function: next] }
>
```

I cannot see my `console.log` printing `dirStatsArray`.

So, how to traverse the directory till first-level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after looking at the module code on github and looking at some closed issues correct way to walk till `1 level` depth is to not call `next()`.

As `next()` forces the recursive call.

https://github.com/coolaj86/node-walk/issues/28

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just use fs and path to traverse a directory non-recursively?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var p = './';

fs.readdir(p, function(err, files) {
  files.map(function(file) {
    return path.join(p, file);
  }).filter(function(file) {
    return fs.statSync(file).isDirectory();
  }).forEach(function(file) {
    console.log(file);
  });
});
```

Comment: I am adding a functionality in one of the open source project on github and it uses `walk` module.  So, am trying to use that module for this functionality